# read image with php not working in server hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to ask

```
$ im = imagecreatefrompng ($ file);
header ('Content-Type: image / png');
imagepng ($ im);
imagedestroy ($ im);
```

Code above works well locally, but in hosting environment returns no image. Anyone knows why ?

Thanks.

Comment: What `get_headers()` / `file_exists()` reports about $file ?

Comment: do you know to make this kind of function in codeigniter?